# Constraints don't work when setting an UIImage inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

When I am setting the `UIImage` in `cellForRowAt` function it looks like the `UIImage` I am setting overlaps the `UIImageView`.

EDITED : `clipsToBound` is marked and `contentMode` is set to `.scaleAspectFit` in the `Storyboard`

I am setting all the `Constraints` in the `Storyboard` as usual:

[image]

But when I run the app it looks something with a bigger priority overpowering the `Constraints` I set and this is what I get :

[image]

A while ago I did a similar thing in other project which worked perfectly fine for me :

[image]

Here is the code for setting the cells, though I am pretty sure I just accidentally marked or unmarked something ing the `Storyboard`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return songArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MainVCCell.CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as? MainVCCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.showLoader()
    cell.songNameLabel.text = songArray[indexPath.row].title

    if songImageArray[songArray[indexPath.row].title] != nil {
        cell.imageView?.image = songImageArray[songArray[indexPath.row].title]!!
        cell.hideLoader()
    }
    cell.setupImageDesign()
    return cell
}
```

Please let me know if any additional information needed, Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove aspect ratio.

Comment: Didn't help, plus I have used the same constraints including aspect ration in the previous project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MainVCCell.CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as? MainVCCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.showLoader()
    cell.songNameLabel.text = songArray[indexPath.row].title

    if songImageArray[songArray[indexPath.row].title] != nil {
        cell.imageView?.image = songImageArray[songArray[indexPath.row].title]!!
        cell.hideLoader()
    }
    cell.setupImageDesign()
    return cell
}
```

`cell.imageView?.image` is default imageView from UITableViewCell.
You must rename your custom UIImageView outlet

Comment: Urgh I knew it was something stupid like that, I called the UIImageView songImageView but called cell.imageView instead of cell.songImageView, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Set the image view `clipsToBounds`to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `contentMode` of UIImageView in storyboard
and also set `clipsToBounds = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Change ContentMode of ImageView to `.scalToFill` and clipping property to `clipToBounds`

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with **Constrain to margins**

Please remove all the constraints and make sure unchecked this option before setting the constraints.

[image]

In Storyboard looks like this

[image]